# LOV in angularjs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, lov

Is there any component that support LOV (list of value) in angularjs?
My problem is like this, I have 2 combo box, the first has too much items, so i decided to provide suggestion to user with typeahead of bootstrap, after a user selects combo an item from combo 1, combo 2 will load some data that depends on combo 1.

essentially, I would like to create the famous state-city component with angular js.

Thanks

EDIT:

Ok, I find this components that are promising,

[AngularUI Select2](http://angular-ui.github.com/), [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/), [Bootstrap Combobox](https://github.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox)

I think I can make it work, but right now I haven't time to try it out. Thanks every one.

Comment: Some sample code or a jsfiddle would come in handy for this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try usint lov-typeahead which is an angularjs directive that implements a list of values using twitter's typeahead: https://github.com/mihaigiurgeanu/lov-typeahead.

If you use bower, you can install it doing:

```
bower install lov-typeahead --save
```

Answer (score 2):

You should read the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api) and [guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide).

Simple use [`ng-model`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel) and [`$watch`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch) for its change. On changing, request states with [`$resource`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource).

Read the docs. If you still can't figure how to implement it, post here again.

Comment: yes, I know that. but typeahead component only accept text, and i want to update second combo with ID of first combo. I want typeahead  to show text but set id (LOV)

Answer (score 1):

What about using a filter in the second combo based on the value on the first one?

http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_03

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this directive will be helpfull too:

https://github.com/rolandocc/lov-angular-directive